# How can I implement a dropdown with 100 default options and the ability to search and retrieve additional options from database using AJAX in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I have 100 options on a select/dropdown and more in the database. Users will select option if available in the dropdown. If not, then the user will search and an ajax will call to get others from database.

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: @dougfabris, Yes, I can call ajax. But How can I implement a Select2 dropdown that displays a set of default options for users to choose from, and also allows searching for additional options in the database using AJAX?